# PVR texture format: MGLPT_PVRTC4 vs OGL_PVRTC4

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, pvrtc

`PVR` texture format from Imaginations.
Defined in [PVRTexLibGlobals.h](https://github.com/TermiT/mkpack/blob/master/PVRTexLib/PVRTexLibGlobals.h)

What is difference with texture formats? 
`MGLPT_PVRTC4` vs `OGL_PVRTC4`

I have used `OGL_PVRTC4` before. Does `MGLPT_PVRTC4` is exactly same?
My code broke when some tool gave `MGLPT_PVRTC4` texture. I am wondering how should we process `MGLPT_PVRTC4` textures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place to ask would be at the PowerVR Insider forum (http://forum.imgtec.com/categories/powervr-graphics). FWIW, MGL is an old API that pre-dates OpenGL ES 1.0 (and the latter recently turned 10).

It is *extremely* likely that the ordering of the contents of the file will have changed between the two.